# lazy binding failed: undefined symbol 'XRRGetScreenInfo' - compiling sfml program on openbsd

Tags: sfml, ld, openbsd

I'm trying to get SFML to work and I ran into this strange problem:

```
clang++ test.cpp -L/usr/local/lib/ -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
./a.out

a.out:/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so.2.0: undefined symbol 'XRRGetScreenInfo'
ld.so: a.out: lazy binding failed!
Killed
```

Doesn't the linker check if the library provides all necessary symbols during compilation?
Is this an indication that the OpenBSD package is broken or is it just some simple environment error?

Comment: What if you add `-lXrandr` when compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After compiling SFML myself the problem disappeared.